# aligning images for responsive design

Tags: html, css

I want to evenly align the two images on either side of the h2 for a responsive design and allow the images to scale down when the browser is reduced, eventually disappearing in small windows such as on mobile devises. Would like to know what I am doing wrong.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobeeornot/Cpua2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the h2 needs to have `float: left;` as well

Answer (score 0):

You also need to create a css sheet that calls for the actions based on the screen size (in pixels)

see link: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbK2A/1/)

All you need then is to use float left

```
#tag-container h2.tag {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #34291c;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    **float: left;**
```

}

Comment: Thanks but that is the next step. Right now I just want to evenly align the images to the desktop. What I am interested in is if my markup and css is right.